# What's a .tpl file in LaTeX and how can i use it?

Tags: latex

What's a .tpl file in LaTeX and how can i use it?

Comment: A template file? What is inside of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tpl` is not an official extension used with LaTeX, but .tpl files are distributed with some packages (e.g., TeXlive) as "templates" to show you how to use various classes and styles.  The idea is that as you are learning, you can create a document by cloning and modifying a .tpl file.